# how to parse integers or decimals in postgres neglecting all other characters?

Tags: postgresql

How do you parse only the numeric values of a mixed field. say '11 ft', and I'm only looking to get 11?

```
SELECT CAST(nullif('11 ft', '') AS integer);
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "11 ft"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to get the first integer from the string, you could use:

```
SELECT substring('11 ft' FROM E'-?[[:digit:]]+')::integer;

 substring 
-----------
        11
(1 row)
```

If you don't want the minus sign to be parsed, remove the `-?`.

Comment: thanks! that works for my specific case, what is the method 'E'?

Comment: Extended string syntax. Not really necessary in this case.